# Load JavaScript before html page

Tags: javascript, html

Im learning JS basics and I need to my html page loads before JS if its possible, I`ve tried

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { code here });
```

But it didnt work, I also tried to put my "script" link in my html body but it didnt change anything, tried to type "defer" in "script", nothing happened.

JS code

```
var lbs = prompt("What is the weight in pounds (lbs)?")
var kg = pounds * 0.454
alert("That is: " + kg + " kilograms")
console.log("Conversion completed")
```

HTML code is just a body with simple Lorem text in p tag

Comment: Note that you have an error in the code: you refer to the variable as `lbs` and then `pounds`.

Comment: Other than that, it _looks_ ok. Please add the full code.

Comment: try to write script end of your body

Comment: looks like it was caused by my mistake in variables, corrected it and it works how it should be, thank you for noticing a variable mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should add it in the bottom of the body

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>CRP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I load my html file, the script appears first and after I input some info into prompt and it shows a alert message and I press ok, only after this html page loads, I tried to put my script at the end of body and it didnt help

Comment: looks like it was caused by my mistake in variables, corrected it and it works how it should be with the script at the end of body, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

DOMContentLoaded event should work. It will be triggered after whole DOM on page is loaded. Maybe try window load event. It will be triggered after the whole page with all references (images, etc.) will be loaded.

Debug all errors you have, like you are using lbs variable and then the pounds variable that is not initialized in your code.

```
window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {});
```

Comment: I guess it was caused by variable mistake, it works correctly even without DOM method but thank you for your response